# Engine idles badly and loudly when I switch on the A/C

Tags: toyota, noise, ac, rough-idle, carina

The engine of my 1984 Toyota Carina AA60 works great when idling without the air conditioner running, but immediately after switching it on, it idles very badly, and a big noise starts up. If I move my car forward, it feels like the engine has a lot of load. Also, the A/C air speed increases with my acceleration. I am hearing a 'click click' noise right after I use the accelerator. This is a terrible feeling when I am in traffic.

We have re-installed an A/C compressor, and the A/C clutch is working very well. The A/C belt is not too tight, but I still have the same problem.

One of my friends said that there may be an issue with the gas inside the compressor. Does that sound right? What else can I look at to solve this problem?

Comment: You say you "re-install an A/C compressor" ... does this mean a new compressor was installed? Did you install, or was it installed professionally? Do you know if the correct oil was put in the compressor? Was it converted from R12 to R134-a?

Comment: Yeah Its a reconditioned compressor.And it installed by professionals(they say they are but they couldn't find a solution for my problem).Regarding the oil,sorry I don't know what they put.

Comment: Something I was just thinking about is you may have a large vacuum leak. When there is a vacuum leak with a load put on the engine, the engine will run very badly. Just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 4):

An AC compressor puts a big strain on an engine when it's engaged. This is especially the case with low horse power 4-cylinder engines. What makes matters worse are high mileage engines which are in poor running condition.

I experienced this with a Saab I used to have. I could only run the AC when I was moving at highway speeds. Otherwise it was too much of a strain on the engine and it would make it run roughly.

I would suggest a tune up and check the overall condition of the engine. There may be something causing loss of power; low compression, bad spark plugs, clogged fuel or air filter, poor quality gas, etc.

As far as the noise, that's kind of difficult to diagnose here. Your best option is to take it to another mechanic to get an their opinion what it causing it.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with my car too. During the 60 000 km check my mehcanic said they had to replace the "AC belt tensioner" because it was in bad condition. It didn't cost too much, worth a try.

That 'click' sound after switching on the AC means that the AC clutch engaged and yes, it could be a bit noisy and it cause a strain for low powered cars. It's kinda normal.

Also, sometimes they 'forgot' to add oil when they fill the AC with gas. When the AC system gets filled is always filled with gas and oil because that oil will grease the compressor.

Hope its helps.

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

Idk about the noise. but, about the idle you could set the idle switch higher. maybe it'll fix a little bit. I have the same problem when i was driving a 1997 Gasoline Pathfider.